# need help to simplify find nth number of occurence

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have this code
I'm trying to return nth many time this occur in my table
so when I input form in my `me.id` it would return this record is the nth record with `ordernum`

```
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim ctr As Integer

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE OrderNum =" & Me.OrderNum, dbOpenDynaset)

    ctr = 0

    With rs

      .MoveLast
      .MoveFirst

         Do Until .EOF
            ctr = ctr + 1
            If rs!ID = Me.ID Then
                MsgBox ctr
            End If
            .MoveNext
         Loop

   End With
```

---

this is the table I have

[image]

so when I input `Ordernum` 300000122 and `ID` 4 it would return 2 (2nd occurence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would simply count the number of occurrences with ID <= (the ID you want)

```
x = DCount("*", "Table1", "OrderNum =" & Me.OrderNum & " AND ID <= " & Me.ID)
```

Comment: Simple, clean and effective! Good one!